# Show nickname instead of username for a ?members command (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

This is my code

```
if (message.content.startsWith("?members")) {
        let roleName = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");

        //Filtering the guild members only keeping those with the role
        //Then mapping the filtered array to their usernames
        let membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
            return member.roles.find(role => role.name.includes(roleName));
        }).map(member => {
            return member.user.username;
        })

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
            "title": `Members in ${roleName}`,
            "description": membersWithRole.join("\n"),
            "color": 0xFFFF

        });

        return message.channel.send(embed);



    }
```

I'm trying to make the embed display people's nicknames in the server instead of their discord usernames. I've tried member.user.nickname, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [displayName](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName). If member has no special nickname on server, `member.nickname` will return **undefined**.

And better first get role, and then map role members.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("?members")) {
        let roleName = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");

        //getRole
        let targetRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.includes(roleName))
        if(!targetRole) return message.channel.send('No role fined')
        let membersWithRole = targetRole.members.map(member => member.displayName) // Embed has max length so you need slice this array to pages if membersWithRole.join("\n").length > 2048

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
            "title": `Members in ${roleName}`,
            "description": membersWithRole.join("\n"),
            "color": 0xFFFF

        });

        return message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

Comment: Embed descriptions are limited to 2048 characters, not 4000 as you mentioned in your comment. See [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits) for details.